# Explicit Specialization of a Derived Class Template

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, explicit-specialization

I have a class template that implements a number of functions. I want to be able to also add specialized version of this class which has only a few functions that override those of the base, when a specific type is declared. I know I could achieve this with a class template and explicit specializations of it. However I also want to:

- Have the explicit specializations uniquely named, similar to how a base and derived class are uniquely named.
- Call the `Base` functions from an instantiated `Derived` object, either inside a `Derived` function, or explicitly as below with `obj1.Foo`

This is the (simplified) example code I am trying to make work:

In myClasses.h

```
template<typename T>
class Base
{
  public: 
    void Foo (T& input);
    virtual void Bar (T& input);
}

template<>
class Derived : public Base<int>
{
  public: 
    void Bar (int& input) override;
}
```

In myClasses.cpp

```
template<typename T>
Base::Foo(T& input) { // Do something generic }

template<typename T>
Base::Bar(T& input) { // Do something generic }

template<>
Derived::Bar(int& input) { // Do something int-dependent }
```

In main.cpp

```
int main()
{
  Base<int> obj1 = new Derived();
  obj1.Foo(input);                  // Runs Base::Foo
  obj1.Bar(input);                  // Runs Derived::Bar
}
```

However this code fails with the `explicit specialization of non-template Derived` error, among others. I've read a lot of StackOverflow threads to get me this far, but I haven't found any that have helped me make this compile. So my questions are:

1. Is combining class templates with class inheritance possible in this way?
2. Why does the compiler label the Derived class a non-template despite me explicitly using that keyword?
3. What is the correct syntax that will make this code work? (assuming what I am trying to do is possible)

**EDIT:** Following the suggesting of HTNW, I can turn `Derived` into a regular class by removing the `template<>` prefix. This will allow everything to compile up to `obj1.Foo(input)`. It seems that the instantiated Derived class can't find or access the base Foo function.

Comment: You don't have a `Derived` template, only a specialization. There needs to be a template to specialize...

Comment: Why can you not just make `Derived`... not a template? `class Derived : public Base<int> { ... };`. The only way to "combine" templates with inheritance that makes any sense to me here is to then use a type trait to find the derived class by giving the choice of `T`: `template<typename T> impl_for { using type = Base<T>; }; template<> impl_for<int> { using type = Derived; };`.

Comment: @ravensgaard So are you essentially saying that the `class Derived : public Base` inheritance only works for actual classes and not class templates/specializations?

Comment: @HTNW, I think I see what you mean, and I think that works. But I'm not sure how to correctly instantiate the `Derived` template - my compilation now fairs in main.cpp

Comment: @Matt No, but there still needs to be a template to specialize. A full specialization is _not_ a template. If your class ever only needs to derive from `Base<int>`, you don't have to make it a template. A normal class _can_ derive from a template class.

Comment: @Matt ? Do you mean you fail to construct an object of type `Derived`? That's because `new Derived()` doesn't have type `Derived`: it allocates a `Derived` on the heap, constructs it there, and returns a `Derived*` pointing to it. Fixes, in order of worst to best: `Base<int> *obj1 = new Derived();`, `std::unique_ptr<Base<int>> obj1 = std::make_unique<Derived>();`, `Base<int> &&obj = Derived();`. Note that the first one leaks memory. That's why you're not supposed to use `new`.

Comment: @ravnsgaard, my understanding of what I have must be wrong. I _think_ that `template<typename T> class Base` is a class template, and that `template<> Class Derived` is a specialization of that template. Which part of this is wrong and why?

Comment: @HTNW, argh typos, yes that's what I meant. Thanks for such a specific answer. If I remove the `template<>` in front of `Derived` then the code seems to compile until I call `obj1.Foo(input)`, I.e. when I call a `Base` object that hasn't been overridden by `Derived`

Comment: @Matt A specialization of Base could be, for instance, `template<> Base<int>`. This allows you to  _replace_ Base's definition with something, supposedly, more appropriate for ints, than the general template provides. This is rarely useful for class templates, but sometimes useful for function templates.

Comment: @ravnsgaard, aaah, so the minute I change the name of `Base<int>` to something else (e.g. trying to create a new object call Derived that inherits it), its no longer a specialization? Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @ravnsgaard It's the exact opposite -- it's more useful for classes (see traits, for example) but it's generally not recommended to specialize function templates (overloading is preferred).

Comment: @cdhowie I'm hardly ever thinking of traits in terms of specializations anymore; they're a vocabulary all of their own. But your point is well taken. And yes, overloading should definitely be preferred to template specializations.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to ravnsgaard and HTNW for the helpful suggestions which got me to a solution. The key was to remove the `template<>` keyword from the `Derived` class (because I wanted it to be a class and not a class template) and declaration of `Base<int>` at the end of the source file. So the working code looks like this:

In myClasses.h

```
template<typename T>
class Base
{
  public: 
    void Foo (T& input);
    virtual void Bar (T& input);
}

class Derived : public Base<int>
{
  public: 
    void Bar (int& input) override;
}
```

in myClasses.cpp

```
template<typename T>
Base::Foo(T& input) { // Do something generic }

template<typename T>
Base::Bar(T& input) { // Do something generic }

Derived::Bar(int& input) { // Do something int-dependent }

template class Base<int>; // VERY IMPORTANT.
```

In main.cpp

```
int main()
{
  Base<int> &&obj1 = Derived();
  obj1.Foo(input);                  // Runs Base::Foo
  obj1.Bar(input);                  // Runs Derived::Bar
}
```

In particular, without the `template class Base<int>;` declaration at the end of myClasses.cpp, the call to `obj1.Foo` will fail with an error complaining that `Derived` has no such function.